# Assembling source code from a text file

Tags: assembly

Okay, I am currently in an Assembly Languages class at school.  We are delving into some source code this week for the first time.  My teacher has given us an example as follows:

```
;plan for getting a, b, c, and displaying ab + bc
call getVal a
mov M1, AX 
call getVal 
mov M2, AX 
call getVal
mov BX, AX 
mul M2
mov CX, AX 
mov AX, M2 
mul M1 
add AX, CX 
call putVal
```

He has told us that we need to save this in a .txt file then from there convert it into a binary executable file to run it.  What's the best way to get this done?  Can it be done through the command line?

EDIT: sorry the code didn't come out just right, but it isn't necessarily important what it does.  I just need to know how to run any source code that is saved as a .txt file

EDIT: Thanks Null

Comment: Try http://flatassembler.net/index.php

Comment: What toolchain are you supposed to use?  Usually all you need to do is pass the code to your assembler & linker, and you'll get an executable.  Have you tried asking your professor?

Comment: I sent him an email, he seems to be a slow responder.  You lost me at "assembler and linker", where can that be obtained?  What do I do once I have the executable?

Answer (score 1):

Assembly language file usually have `.s` `.S` or `.asm` but not `.txt` even it doesn't matter.

As asked, you should precise a bit your question giving the machine type and toolchain.

This really looks like an Intel-mnemonic assembly using Intel assembly (vs AT&T, see [Wikipedia x86 assembly](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_assembly_language#Syntax) for a quick overview).

You can try [NASM (The Netwide Assembler)](http://www.nasm.us) to compile such source code.

Of course, some parts are missing in your file as stated by NASM (**under Linux**).

```
$ cat file.s
; comment
section .text
    global fct
fct:
    call getVal
    mov M1, AX 
    call getVal 
    mov M2, AX 
    call getVal
    mov BX, AX 
    mul M2
    mov CX, AX 
    mov AX, M2 
    mul M1 
    add AX, CX 
    call putVal
$ nasm -f elf -o file.o file.s
file.s:5: error: symbol `getVal' undefined
file.s:6: error: symbol `M1' undefined
file.s:7: error: symbol `getVal' undefined
file.s:8: error: symbol `M2' undefined
file.s:9: error: symbol `getVal' undefined
file.s:11: error: symbol `M2' undefined
file.s:13: error: symbol `M2' undefined
file.s:14: error: symbol `M1' undefined
file.s:16: error: symbol `putVal' undefined
```

Note that I used ELF output format as it helps using `GNU objdump`. But you can choose another output fomat within the following list (`nasm -hf`):

```
valid output formats for -f are (`*' denotes default):
  * bin       flat-form binary files (e.g. DOS .COM, .SYS)
    ith       Intel hex
    srec      Motorola S-records
    aout      Linux a.out object files
    aoutb     NetBSD/FreeBSD a.out object files
    coff      COFF (i386) object files (e.g. DJGPP for DOS)
    elf32     ELF32 (i386) object files (e.g. Linux)
    elf       ELF (short name for ELF32) 
    elf64     ELF64 (x86_64) object files (e.g. Linux)
    as86      Linux as86 (bin86 version 0.3) object files
    obj       MS-DOS 16-bit/32-bit OMF object files
    win32     Microsoft Win32 (i386) object files
    win64     Microsoft Win64 (x86-64) object files
    rdf       Relocatable Dynamic Object File Format v2.0
    ieee      IEEE-695 (LADsoft variant) object file format
    macho32   NeXTstep/OpenStep/Rhapsody/Darwin/MacOS X (i386) object files
    macho     MACHO (short name for MACHO32)
    macho64   NeXTstep/OpenStep/Rhapsody/Darwin/MacOS X (x86_64) object files
    dbg       Trace of all info passed to output stage
```

For MS users, you could have used `MASM` or `TASM` which use another assembly-style code:

```
; comment
.CODE
fct:
   [...]
END
```

Hope it helps :)